# How to run any program with Windows Service as an Administrator privilage

Tags: c#, service, installation, auto, administrator

I wrote a code in C# which generates exe and also created a windows service for it.

This windows service simply starts the process of my main program (exe).

When I'm installing the windows service with windows installer which also created by me, everything is ok. My service is installing and it is running my main program. But because it is running it with SYSTEM privileges, my program isn't running as expected.

Is there any way to run it with Administrator privileges?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the service as a specific user by opening up your windows services.

Push the windows key on your keyboard. Then type services.msc and then

Right click on the service you created and click properties.

Go to the "Log On" tab and change from "Local System account" to "This account:"

Then provide credentials for elevated user that has necessary rights.

(Edit) NOTES:
when you enter your username and password into that box.. it only validates your username is valid. it does not validate the password is correct. Ensure that your credentials are entered correctly.

Comment: I tried this. My main program still starting with SYSTEM privilage. Its not working.

Comment: Did you set the credentials and then stop the service and restart? One thing to note.. when you enter your username and password into that box.. it only validates your username is valid. it does not validate the password is correct. Ensure that your credentials are entered correctly.

Comment: I tried this. Its not working. i used temporarily task scheduler

Comment: bummer, am doing this in a production environment and it works great